# Cannot reset asp.net @User.Identity.Name

Tags: asp.net, identity

After cleaning session in forms mode authentication @User.Identity.Name in razor pagestill has value (domaine\username). Why ?

Web.config :

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="30" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

IIS :

Anonymymous authentication -> activated

Forms authentication -> activated

Logoff code :

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
Session.Abandon();

// Clear authentication cookie
HttpCookie cookie1 = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, "");
cookie1.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie1);

// Clear session cookie
SessionStateSection sessionStateSection = (SessionStateSection)WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/sessionState");
HttpCookie cookie2 = new HttpCookie(sessionStateSection.CookieName, "");
cookie2.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie2);

return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

Comment: is windows authentication switched on in IIS? a format of `domain\username` as you describe normally indicates the use of Windows auth.

Comment: Thanks, windows auth was actually disabled but I was using iis express instead of my local iis website with proper configuration. Don't know how to configure iis express authentication thou

Comment: If you're running the app under IIS express, your main IIS settings will have no effect at all. There's no GUI for IIS Express config, the config file can be hand-edited and is usually located at `%userprofile%\documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config`. You can check in there what is enabled and what is not.

Comment: You can also use the `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` property to check whether it thinks you are still signed in or not.